# XAML Windows 8 Vertical orientation with Header and ItemTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows

I'm having trouble trying to get my GridView Itemtemplate to sit vertically under my Gridview header. At the moment, it floats to the right of the header and I can't get it to "clear" and sit underneath. Here is my code:

```
<GridView Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding TestData, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionMode="Multiple" IsSwipeEnabled="true" IsItemClickEnabled="true" Grid.Row="1" Width="417">                        
<GridView.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="Measures" Margin="10,0,0,18" Style="{StaticResource SectionTitle}"/>
</GridView.Header>                        
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid> 
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Text="Here is some form text!!" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0,0,10,0" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="right">
                <ComboBoxItem>N/A</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Existing</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Proposed</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="right" Text="Date" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you actually want to use the Header and not the Grouping functions ?
[Grouping GridView in Windows 8 Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861736/grouping-gridview-in-windows-8-metro-app)

If you want a static header on the top of your grid, do you really need it to be a part of the grid or simply:

```
 <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Measures"/>

        <GridView Grid.Row="1">

            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" />
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" />
            <GridViewItem Content="GridViewItem" />

        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I've tried that and it worked. Good point Souch - thanks very much for your help ! I'm still learning here :)

Answer (score 0):

Your header TextBlock has a left margin set to 10, and the default margin on your GridView is 0. You can remove the header margin to make it align like you wish.